# git2r::summary() produces different results when called from console and by RStudio

Tags: r, git, rstudio, testthat

I am trying to write an R package that analyzes [Apache Pig GitHub repository](https://github.com/apache/pig) with the help of `git2r` package. I also use `testthat` package for unit testing.

I have a function, let's call it `compute()`, which contains code along the lines of:

```
repo <- repository("C:\normalized\path\to\apache\pig");
allCommits <- commits(repo);
commitSummary <- capture.output(summary(allCommits[[1]]));
print(commitSummary);
```

The `commitSummary` is an important part, because I run several regexes on it to recover data like insertions and deletions.

The problem is, when I call `compute()` from console, it prints out *Output 1*.

But when `compute()` is called from my unit test file when I run `devtools::test()`, it prints out *Output 2*. (And over the course of me writing this question, after producing *Output 2* several times, it produced *Output 3*.)

When I run the first codeblock in this question from the console, it prints out *Output 1*, again.

However, when I copy-paste that codeblock into the test file, it prints out *Output 3*.

I am confused. How is that even possible?

And how can I make sure `git2r::summary()` uses the format I want?

---

### Output 1

```
[1] "Commit:  d2de56aad939c7c77324066a6f29cc211e29a077"                                                       
 [2] "Author:  Koji Noguchi <knoguchi@apache.org>"                                                             
 [3] "When:    2016-12-12 23:07:37"                                                                            
 [4] ""                                                                                                        
 [5] "     PIG-5073: Skip e2e Limit_5 test for Tez (knoguchi)"                                                 
 [6] "     "                                                                                                   
 [7] "     "                                                                                                   
 [8] "     git-svn-id: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk@1773899 13f79535-47bb-0310-9956-ffa450edef68"
 [9] "     "                                                                                                   
[10] "2 files changed, 18 insertions, 1 deletions"                                                             
[11] "CHANGES.txt                     | -0 + 2  in 1 hunk"                                                     
[12] "test/e2e/pig/tests/nightly.conf | -1 +16  in 2 hunks"                                                    
[13] ""
```

### Output 2

```
[d2de56a] 2016-12-12: PIG-5073: Skip e2e Limit_5 test for Tez (knoguchi)
```

### Output 3

```
[1] "    Length      Class       Mode " "         1 git_commit         S4 "
```

---

#### Additional notes that might take away from question's clarity

1. When I load and call the function calling `compute()` from the unit test file, it prints out *Output 1*. Same for calling `compute()` from working directory set to test folder and exactly same arguments.
2. To make matters more confusing, up until very recently `devtools::test()` produced *Output 1*, then it switched to *Output 3* before settling on *Output 2*.
3. CRAN's documentation for `git2r::summary(object, ...)` lists following arguments:

   > 

   - `object`  The commit object.
   - `...`  Additional arguments affecting the summary produced.

   Accepted values of `...` are nowhere to be found.

Comment: RStudio may be loading a different libgit version (for its own use, recall that its git interface has to be built against something too...)  than git2r, and could potentially hide the that git2r wants.  I'd trust the command-line.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I guess that's a start. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there is probably some sort of a namespace-related race condition going on, since there is already a `summary()` function in base R (and [probably some other packages](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/why-summary-does-not-work-here-td901562.html)), which explains why there were 3 different outputs.

I just changed every

```
summary(commitObject)
```

into

```
git2r::summary(commitObject)
```

and everything seems to work again.

Comment: (I'm still surprised the decision which package's `summary()` to choose is effectively random, though.)